# Perl: Passing Unicode string to chr()

Tags: perl, unicode, chr

I'm pretty new to Perl so pardon me for what will probably turn into a most obvious answer.

I'm trying to pass a Unicode markup to the `chr()` function.
Here's a redacted example of my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$unicode = "/u0026amp;";
print chr("0x".substr($unicode, 4, 2))."\n";
```

This properly extracts the *26* from the *$unicode* variable.
However the problem as I can tell is that the `chr()` function doesn't like quoted strings, but if I remove the quotes the *x* in *0x* gets removed and becomes an invalid 026 rather than a valid 0x26.

Anyways, this really gets down to. How can I keep the x in

```
chr("0x".substr($unicode, 4, 2))
```

from disappearing and send the proper 0x26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use "0x" strings with `chr`, the way you can with `ord` and `hex`.  So you want:

```
 chr(hex($hexstring))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was spot on. I'm still not sure why directly using 0x26 works but not through passing or concatenation. Edit: I should mention my final solution was: chr(hex(substr($unicode, 4, 2)))

Comment: @Aurelius: Because the rules for numeric literals like 0x26 or 046 or 0b100110  or 186_242 are not the rules used for converting strings into numbers, which are much stricter and decimal only.